# comparing objects in image

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

I have two images in the pdf which are of different sizes. First I extract the images, later I need to find the similarities of the object, to check whether both the images contains same objects or not.

Which algorithm can be used? Which is the best and fastest way to compare the objects in the two images?

Comment: what kind of images are those? Bitmap images? Vector images?

Comment: Images are of  vector a well as bitmap .

Comment: Extracting bitmap images from pdfs using iTextSharpis pretty straight forward using the parser classes with a RenderListener with an appropriate RenderImage implementation. The comparison itself then is not a question of the PDF library you used. Thus, you might want to change the tags of your question. Vector images are a bit more difficult, though, as iText currently sites not export them with the parser classes.

Comment: I agree with @mkl. If you've already extracted the images from a PDF then this has nothing to do with iTextSharp, you're question is just about comparing images.